# Successfully populating an html table with multiple ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using an ajax api call to populate an html table. The first column of the table is an the (item.name) and I am nesting a second ajax call to populate the second column with a date (as an aside, the date is returned in microseconds since epoch... I will work on formatting this later). The reason I am nesting is because the second call is using part of the results from the first call in the url. Here is the code:

HTML

```
<div id="output">
    <table id="scalaapi">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td class="uuid"></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: "https://avacmd25.scala.com:44335/ContentManager/api/rest/players?offset=0&sort=name&filters=%7BplayerStatus%20:%20%7Bvalues:%5B'HEARTBEAT_OVERDUE'%5D,%20comparator%20:%20'eq'%7D%7D",
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {
var list = data.list;
$.each(list, function(i, item) {
var tr = $('<tr>').append('<td>' + (item.name) + '</td>' + '<td>'+ 
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://avacmd25.scala.com:44335/ContentManager/api/rest/heartbeats/sequence/"+(item.uuid),
    dataType: "text",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: $.each(function(results) { 
                $('.uuid').text(results);
            })
    })
    + '</td>');
$("#scalaapi").append(tr);
});
}
})
```

I am getting a mixed result... The first api call is working as expected, though it is skipping the first row.
The second api call is only returning the first record and it is not skipping the first row and the subsequent rows show [object Object]

Screen shot of resuts -

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing a lot in your code where you're immediately doing things without waiting for AJAX calls to complete first. Try restructuring your javascript to be a little more patient (below is pseudocode where I've stripped out most of the extra AJAX config stuff to hopefully make it clearer what the code is doing):

```
$.ajax({..., success: function(data) {
    // when we get here the first AJAX call has returned

    // loop through each item in the response from the first AJAX call
    $.each(data.list, function(i, item) {
        // append the <tr> to the table with the information we have for the item and a placeholder for the second cell
        var tr = $('<tr><td>'+item.name+'</td><td class="uuid">...</td></tr>').appendTo('#scalaapi');

        // make the second AJAX call for this item
        $.ajax({
            url:".../sequence/"+item.uuid,
            ...,
            success: function(result) {
                // we now have the contents we need for the second <td>, so insert it
                tr.find('.uuid').text(result);
            }
         });
    });
});
```

I believe that will get you closer to what you're trying to do?